# How do we show $P(A) \leq P(A \Delta B) + P(A \cap B) \leq P(A\Delta B) + P(B).$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, inequality, random

In some questions I have been going through here, I came across this inequality several times.

$A$ and $B$ are RV. How do we show
$$P(A) \leq P(A \Delta B) + P(A \cap B) \leq P(A\Delta B) + P(B)$$.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ ae r.v.'s, so $P(A\ne B)$ makes  sense. But $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ doesnt make sense as $A$ and  $B$ are not events.

Comment: @QED ... and it is certainl not true that $|E(A) − E(B)| \le P(A \ne B)$ .  Maybe the OP wants $|P(A) − P(B)| \le P(A \Delta B)$ for events $A,B$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you meant $\lvert{P(A)-P(B)}\rvert \leq P(A\Delta B)$

$A \subseteq (A \Delta B) \cup (A \cap B)$, and the two sets on the RHS are disjoint. So $P(A) \leq P(A \Delta B) + P(A \cap B) \leq P(A\Delta B) + P(B).$

So $P(A) - P(B) \leq P(A\Delta B)$. We can similarly show that $P(B)-P(A) \leq P(A\Delta B)$ and the result follows.